# Toggling the "Network Authentication" capability for accessing network folders requires user to log out and log back in?

Tags: uwp, windows-10

```
Imports Windows.Storage

Public NotInheritable Class MainPage
    Inherits Page

    Protected Overrides Async Sub OnNavigatedTo(e As NavigationEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnNavigatedTo(e)
        Dim folder As StorageFolder = Await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(<network share path>)
        For Each f In Await folder.GetFoldersAsync()
            Debug.WriteLine(f.Name)
        Next
        Dim x = 1
    End Sub

End Class
```

Add the following capabilities:

- Enterprise Authentication
- Internet (Client)
- Private Networks (Client    & Server)

Run the application. It should work as expected. Remove "Enterprise Authentication" capability. Run the application. It should throw an Unauthorized Access exception. Re-add the "Enterprise Authentication" capability. Run the application. I still get the Unauthorized Access exception. In order get the application to work properly, I must log out and log back in. Has anyone encountered this? And/or have any insight into why this is happening?

Comment: Can not reproduce, when add the "Enterprise Authentication" capability again, it works well as expect. You can try to test it again in a new UWP app.

Comment: @BreezeLiu-MSFT This is the new UWP app I used to troubleshoot after I experienced unauthorized access in a previous project.